# how to get collectionLink azure cosmodb

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

what is collectionLink how to get this, and where it is..  how to get collectionLink ??? where it is .... its require.. anyone help me i am its `require`(collectionLink, Query);`

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetJoin()
        {

            DocumentClient client;

            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(appVars.Endpoint), appVars.Key);
            string Query = "SELECT f.id AS familyName f.DisplayName AS childGivenName, c.EntityTypeName AS childFirstName "+
                "FROM EntiyMaster f JOIN c IN f.EntityType ";
            IEnumerable<dynamic>dataour = client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(collectionLink, Query);
            return dataour;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `collectionLink` is the link to the `Collection` resource that you are operating against.

There are two types of `collectionLinks` (or any resource links for that matter).

- The SelfLink, which is a link that uses the resource ids to point to a resource and it looks like this: `dbs/7tNCAA==/colls/7tNCAMHd0xU=/`
- The AltLink, which is a link that uses the `id` property ids to point to a resource and it looks like this: `dbs/databaseId/colls/collectionId/`

Both of these links will point to the resource, which in this case is the collection.

However you can generate the AltLink yourself if you have the `id` properties.

The `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.UriFactory` is a class in the CosmosDB SDK that can generate these AltLinks.

You can use the following line to generate the AltLink of a document collection:

`UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);`

The `UriFactory.CreateCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);` one that's suggested on another answer will work but do not use it as it is obsolete and it will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

The `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.UriFactory` class is your friend for these identifiers.

```
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.UriFactory.CreateCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);
```

It also allows you to generate links for databases and individual documents as long as you have their ids.